# Why is the bootstrap badge always the default color?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, badge

I use the bootstrap badge in my html code and I use this code:

```
<label for="collaborativa_utenti_pollo"><span class="badge badge-warning">pollo</span><br></label>
```

The badge must be show with red color but it appears me with default color. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Bootstrap v4:**

For red color badge, use `badge-danger`

```
<label for="collaborativa_utenti_pollo"><span class="badge badge-danger">pollo</span><br></label>
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/mearaf9r/

**Bootstrap v3**

Check here - https://jsfiddle.net/pf66jvfr/

you have to use `progress-bar-danger` to color the badge.

```
<label for="collaborativa_utenti_pollo"><span class="badge progress-bar-danger">pollo</span><br></label>
```

Comment: ...but wouldn't he have seen orange anyway? Not "default". Who knows.

Comment: @mayersdesign I agree. Not sure what OP means by "default". But if his goal is red, this is the way to go.

Comment: It doesn't work in my code :( . I read the jsfidlle and I copy the code but it doesn't work

Comment: @Picco Can you elaborate on that? do you see the wrong color? no badge at all?

Comment: @sparta93 I see the defaul badge. Go in this page :  https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_badges_labels.asp  I see the default badge in Grey also if in my code I specifie that I want a warning (or danger) badge!

Comment: @Sparta93 I use Bootstrap 3.0.0

Comment: @Picco check my answer for v3

Comment: The problem is my bootstrap's version. I work with bootstrap 3.0.0 but the "badge badge-danger" work with bootstrap 4.0.0  :( Thank for your support!

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code to make a badge with bootstrap warning background:

`<span class="badge bg-danger">pollo</span>`

`bg-danger` class can be used to set danger the background color. In bootstrap's documentation there is no class mentioned as `badge-danger`.

Comment: OP wants red, not orange

Comment: For some reason, for me, `<span class="badge badge-danger">` does not work (badge is the default/dark bg color), and I had to use `bg-danger` instead of `badge-danger`. This goes against what's in the docs.

Comment: Bootstrap 4.6 docs do include `badge-*` classes, but as mentioned above, they were not working for me: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/badge/#contextual-variations